# Teradata UNION not working correctly. blank values for a column when UNION used

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Wondering if anyone has come across this issue before. I have a query as follows that never had an issue against a SQL Server database, but now I'm having an issue with Teradata.

When each of the individual `SELECT` statements are executed, all columns contain data. When run together with UNION as below, the second `SELECT` statement yields a blank values for the 'SR.yyy' column. Likewise, if I swap the SELECT statements (i.e. first SELECT statement is now after the UNION and vice versa), then the 'SR.yyy' column contains values however, the 'SG.xxx' column is now blank. Puzzling.

Note: all columns are of same data type.

```
SELECT AA.name, AA.id, SG.xxx, '' as yyy   
FROM DATABASE1 AA  
LEFT JOIN DATABASE_SG SG ON AA.id = SG.id  
WHERE AA.name = 'John.Doe'  
UNION  
SELECT AA.name, AA.id, '' as xxx,  SR.yyy  
FROM DATABASE1 AA  
LEFT JOIN DATABASE_SR SR ON AA.id = SR.id  
WHERE AA.name = 'John.Doe'
```

Comment: A SQL statement returns an *unordered* result set.  If you want results in a particular order, then use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The 1st Select determines the resulting data types in Teradata, in your case yyy will be a VARCHAR(0). CAST it to a larger VarChar matching SR.yyy, e.g.`CAST('' AS VARCHAR(10))`

Comment: @dnoeth thank you, this worked!  Appreciate the prompt response. Didn't know the default was '0'.